# Adding a new constraint in postgresql checks the rows added before?

Tags: postgresql, constraints

Let's suppose I have a table called `Clients(ID,Name,Phone)` which has several rows in it, with some of them empty in the column «Phone».

If I decide to add a new `NOT NULL` constraint to said table in the column «Phone», does PostgreSQL will check the rows that were already in the table, or is it only going to work to the rows added after the constraint's declaration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altertable.html) is pretty clear:

> SET/DROP NOT NULL
>
> These forms change whether a column is marked to allow null values or
>   to reject null values. You can only use SET NOT NULL when the column
>   contains no null values.

So, using this form, you cannot add such a constraint without checking the previous values.

If you use `add table_constraint`, then you can do the same thing using a `CHECK` cosntraint:

> ADD table_constraint [ NOT VALID ]
>
> This form adds a new constraint to a table using the same syntax as
>   CREATE TABLE, plus the option NOT VALID, which is currently only
>   allowed for foreign key and CHECK constraints. If the constraint is
>   marked NOT VALID, the potentially-lengthy initial check to verify that
>   all rows in the table satisfy the constraint is skipped. The
>   constraint will still be enforced against subsequent inserts or
>   updates (that is, they'll fail unless there is a matching row in the
>   referenced table, in the case of foreign keys; and they'll fail unless
>   the new row matches the specified check constraints). But the database
>   will not assume that the constraint holds for all rows in the table,
>   until it is validated by using the VALIDATE CONSTRAINT option.

So, you cannot add a `NOT NULL` constraint using `alter table`.  You can do essentially the same thing using `CHECK`.  Then, you by-pass the checking using `NOT VALID`.  Otherwise, the checking takes place.